# Do I need to encrypt the content sent via SSL connection?

Tags: ssl

Is there any extra benefit to encrypt the content (text) sent via SSL connection? Is it more secure than sending the content as plain text, or it doesn't make any difference as long as the connection is SSL. Thank you.

Comment: Beside the fact that I can’t imagine how this would provide a security benefit, how do you expect a random client to *decrypt* your message without exposing the secret to an “attacker” (whoever that would be in your scenario)?

Comment: What if an attacker intercepts the message? Will a "plain text" ssl message be easier to decrypt than a "encrypted text" ssl message?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868320/ssl-additional-layer-of-encryption , pretty much the same issue is discussed there. In summary: The idea of another layer of encryption is nonsensical.

Comment: got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, an SSL connections encrypts the data. You will not make the connection more secure.